# Receiving Outlook calendar reminders from an obsolete work account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

I've been experiencing a strange phenomenon with regards to Outlook calendar reminders from an obsolete work account that I can't seem to find a solution for.

I used to work for an employer that utilized Microsoft Office. For convenience purposes, I added my personal email account to my work Outlook, so that I could quickly add appointments or contacts throughout the day. Well, six months ago I retired and prior to my last work day, I deleted my personal user profile from my work Outlook. Fast forward to today, I'm continuously receiving Outlook calendar reminders from my old work account, such as meetings and birthday notifications. I'm quite certain that the IT department has long deleted my user profile. I've tried everything to get rid of these annoying reminders, including uninstalling and reinstalling Office on my home computer but to no avail. Has anyone else ever experienced this issue?

In case it matters, I'm running Office Professional Plus 2019 on a 64-bit system.

Thanks in advance for everyone's feedback!

Comment: You still using your old work computer, or is this a different computer?

Comment: If these items are indeed coming **from** your former work account, their IT most certainly did not delete that account.

Comment: Hi Moab, I'm only using my home computer. I no longer have access to my work computer, but am still getting the calendar reminders, because I had linked my personal account to my work Outlook.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator... I will check with the IT guy to see if perhaps they have not deleted my account yet. They are usually pretty fast in doing so and since it's been five months, I'd think it's long completed, but one just never knows- it may have fallen through the cracks. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @ Perry Thank you for your reply and instructions. I followed your steps outlined above, however, when typing 'outlook/cleanreminders' into the command box, I get the following notification: "Windows cannot find 'outlook/cleanreminders'. Make sure you type the name correctly and then try again." It appears that some time back, I had tried a similar approach, because I got an auto suggestion of 'outlook.exe/cleanreminders' in the command box. I suppose that is another way of accomplishing the same task?

Comment: @Perry cont'd. If so, I just closed out Outlook, ran the command again and, per your suggestion, also removed my account from the Mail app. I'm going to wait it out now and see what happens tomorrow. On Tuesdays, I usually get a meeting invitation, so if it pops up again, I will try to apply the third option of deleting the Reminders folder by using MAPI Editor. I will keep you posted. Thanks again!

Comment: OK. Hope that works

Comment: So, I contacted my IT Department and was assured that my user profile was deleted on the last day of my employment. They also deleted my profile off of the actual desktop that I was using, so it's definitely not an issue on their end. I was able to narrow things down to Microsoft Outlook though since I only get those pesty reminders when using that particular app. If I access my email account through Windows Mail App or www.outlook.com online, I do NOT get those reminders. It only happens in MS Outlook on both my desktop and laptop computers.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to fix this would be to delete the email account that I had linked to my work Outlook, but I have all my contacts, appointments and OneDrive linked to it, so that's not an option. Does anyone else have any suggestions as to what else could be done? TIA for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the email account has been removed from client but you still receive reminders?

Try /cleanreminders switch to clear and regenerate reminders:

Exit Outlook. press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook /cleanreminders and then press Enter

If you are using Windows 10, please also check if your account was automatically added to Mail app. If yes, remove it.

If issue continues, delete the Reminders folder by using the Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Editor (MFCMAPI).

Check steps in [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ebbe8136-536c-4ec9-9389-c232bb52bcf8/knowledge-sharing-how-to-dismiss-reminders-for-past-events?forum=outlook)